# Link text still underlined when "text-decoration: none" is applied

Tags: drupal, css, drupal-7

I am working on a page in Drupal 7 in which I have a number of boxes with text and a photo inside of them. I have the entire box div linking to its content page, but I can't seem to get rid of the underline.

I have tried applying `text-decoration: none;` to every class inside of and outside of the box and the text inside the box is still underlined.

Even when I use developer tools/'inspect element' tool in Google it shows that the computed style for the box and the text within is `text-decoration: none;`

I have been trying to figure this out off and on for about a day now and I have not been able to find any solutions via Google.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am working to post my code. I am trying to find a good solution for posting because it is a page within Drupal that is rendering through Views. Also, I have a job interview in an hour that I'm getting ready for. I probably should have waited until after the interview to post this issue.. oh well.

Edit x2: My HTML is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" class="js"><head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)">
  <title>Portfolio Page | mywebsite.com</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://url.com/modules/system/system.base.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/system/system.menus.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/system/system.messages.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/system/system.theme.css?m178g6");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://url.com/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/overlay/overlay-parent.css?m178g6");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://url.com/modules/comment/comment.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/field/theme/field.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/node/node.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/search/search.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/user/user.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?m178g6");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/modules/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/views_slideshow.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?m178g6");
@import url("http://url.com/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?m178g6");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/themes/personal/css/style.css?m178g6");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/themes/personal/css/print.css?m178g6");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="mobile">@import url("http://url.com/sites/all/themes/personal/css/mobile.css?m178g6");</style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/misc/drupal.js?m178g6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?v=1.8.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/sites/all/modules/views/js/views-contextual.js?m178g6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/misc/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.2.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/misc/jquery.cookie.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/sites/all/modules/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js?1332273397"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/js/views_slideshow.js?m178g6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/modules/toolbar/toolbar.js?m178g6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"personal","theme_token":"0CkOwyp1neNP-2IbE8LYCgYGBJ9sz39ORy5DodizAGg","js":{"misc\/jquery.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/js\/views-contextual.js":1,"misc\/jquery.ba-bbq.js":1,"modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.js":1,"misc\/jquery.cookie.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/lightbox2\/js\/lightbox.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow\/js\/views_slideshow.js":1,"modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,"modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/css\/views.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/lightbox2\/css\/lightbox.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow\/views_slideshow.css":1,"modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,"modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/personal\/css\/style.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/personal\/css\/print.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/personal\/css\/mobile.css":1}},"lightbox2":{"rtl":0,"file_path":"\/(\\w\\w\/)public:\/","default_image":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/lightbox2\/images\/brokenimage.jpg","border_size":10,"font_color":"000","box_color":"fff","top_position":"","overlay_opacity":"0.8","overlay_color":"000","disable_close_click":true,"resize_sequence":0,"resize_speed":400,"fade_in_speed":400,"slide_down_speed":600,"use_alt_layout":false,"disable_resize":false,"disable_zoom":false,"force_show_nav":false,"show_caption":true,"loop_items":false,"node_link_text":"View Image Details","node_link_target":false,"image_count":"Image !current of !total","video_count":"Video !current of !total","page_count":"Page !current of !total","lite_press_x_close":"press \u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 onclick=\u0022hideLightbox(); return FALSE;\u0022\u003E\u003Ckbd\u003Ex\u003C\/kbd\u003E\u003C\/a\u003E to close","download_link_text":"Download Original","enable_login":false,"enable_contact":false,"keys_close":"c x 27","keys_previous":"p 37","keys_next":"n 39","keys_zoom":"z","keys_play_pause":"32","display_image_size":"","image_node_sizes":"()","trigger_lightbox_classes":"","trigger_lightbox_group_classes":"","trigger_slideshow_classes":"","trigger_lightframe_classes":"","trigger_lightframe_group_classes":"","custom_class_handler":0,"custom_trigger_classes":"","disable_for_gallery_lists":true,"disable_for_acidfree_gallery_lists":true,"enable_acidfree_videos":true,"slideshow_interval":5000,"slideshow_automatic_start":true,"slideshow_automatic_exit":true,"show_play_pause":true,"pause_on_next_click":false,"pause_on_previous_click":true,"loop_slides":false,"iframe_width":600,"iframe_height":400,"iframe_border":1,"enable_video":false},"overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*","non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"},"ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"},"tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.toolbar.height"});
//--><!]]>
</script>
</head>
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-portfolio toolbar toolbar-drawer lightbox-processed" style="padding-top: 65px; ">
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay-disable-message" class="clearfix"><h3 class="element-invisible">Options for the administrative overlay</h3><a href="/user/1/edit?destination=portfolio#edit-overlay-control" id="overlay-profile-link" class="overlay-exclude element-invisible">If you have problems accessing administrative pages on this site, disable the overlay on your profile page.</a> <a href="/overlay/dismiss-message?destination=portfolio&amp;token=snk0Img0V_hSox1Q_-De1dEEDTtRR_v0O00J3BOSulg" id="overlay-dismiss-message" class="overlay-exclude element-invisible">Dismiss this message.</a></div><div id="toolbar" class="toolbar overlay-displace-top clearfix toolbar-processed">
  <div class="toolbar-menu clearfix">
    <ul id="toolbar-home"><li class="home first last"><a href="/" title="Home"><span class="home-link">Home</span></a></li>
</ul>    <ul id="toolbar-user"><li class="account first"><a href="/user" title="User account">Hello <strong>user</strong></a></li>
<li class="logout last"><a href="/user/logout">Log out</a></li>
</ul>    <h2 class="element-invisible">Administrative toolbar</h2><ul id="toolbar-menu"><li class="menu-11 path-admin-dashboard first"><a href="/admin/dashboard" id="toolbar-link-admin-dashboard" title="View and customize your dashboard."><span class="icon"></span>Dashboard <span class="element-invisible">(View and customize your dashboard.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-9 path-admin-content"><a href="/admin/content" id="toolbar-link-admin-content" title="Administer content and comments."><span class="icon"></span>Content <span class="element-invisible">(Administer content and comments.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-21 path-admin-structure"><a href="/admin/structure" id="toolbar-link-admin-structure" title="Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc."><span class="icon"></span>Structure <span class="element-invisible">(Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-7 path-admin-appearance"><a href="/admin/appearance" id="toolbar-link-admin-appearance" title="Select and configure your themes."><span class="icon"></span>Appearance <span class="element-invisible">(Select and configure your themes.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-18 path-admin-people"><a href="/admin/people" id="toolbar-link-admin-people" title="Manage user accounts, roles, and permissions."><span class="icon"></span>People <span class="element-invisible">(Manage user accounts, roles, and permissions.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-16 path-admin-modules"><a href="/admin/modules" id="toolbar-link-admin-modules" title="Extend site functionality."><span class="icon"></span>Modules <span class="element-invisible">(Extend site functionality.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-8 path-admin-config"><a href="/admin/config" id="toolbar-link-admin-config" title="Administer settings."><span class="icon"></span>Configuration <span class="element-invisible">(Administer settings.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-19 path-admin-reports"><a href="/admin/reports" id="toolbar-link-admin-reports" title="View reports, updates, and errors."><span class="icon"></span>Reports <span class="element-invisible">(View reports, updates, and errors.)</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-12 path-admin-help last"><a href="/admin/help" id="toolbar-link-admin-help" title="Reference for usage, configuration, and modules."><span class="icon"></span>Help <span class="element-invisible">(Reference for usage, configuration, and modules.)</span></a></li>
</ul>          <a href="/toolbar/toggle?destination=portfolio" title="Hide shortcuts" class="toggle toggle-active toolbar-toggle-processed">Hide shortcuts</a>      </div>

  <div class="toolbar-drawer clearfix">
    <div class="toolbar-shortcuts"><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/node/add">Add content</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/admin/content">Find content</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/admin/config/development/performance">Performance</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/admin/config/development/maintenance">Maintenance mode</a></li>
</ul></div><a href="/admin/config/user-interface/shortcut/shortcut-set-1" id="edit-shortcuts">Edit shortcuts</a>  </div>
</div>
  <!-- If front page, present front page content -->
<div id="a">
<!-- Begin other page specific content -->
<div id="smallhead">
</div>
</div><!-- End div a-->
<!-- Begin menu -->
<div id="b">
<div id="menu">
<a href="/home"><div class="item">Home</div></a>
<a href="/about"><div class="item">About Me</div></a>
<a href="/portfolio"><div class="item">Portfolio</div></a>
<a href="/photos"><div class="item">Photos</div></a>
<a href="/projects"><div class="item">Projects</div></a>
<a href="/blog"><div class="item">Blog</div></a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="c">
<div id="middle">
<!-- Begin other page specific content -->
<div id="contentwrapper">
  <div class="region region-content">
    <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">


  <div class="content">
    <div class="view view-portfolio-page view-id-portfolio_page view-display-id-page view-dom-id-a0c892fe2818834f0a7750c98e7e6688">



      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">

  <div>        <div><a href="/node/10">
<div class="smallbox">
<div class="nounderline">
<strong>Postcards</strong><br>
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" width="233" height="157" alt=""><br>
Postcards<br>
Adobe Illustrator
</div>
</div></a></div>  </div>  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">

  <div>        <div><a href="/node/9">
<div class="smallbox">
<div class="nounderline">
<strong>Design</strong><br>
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" width="233" height="157" alt=""><br>
Desiugn<br>
Adobe Illustrator
</div>
</div></a></div>  </div>  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">

  <div>        <div><a href="/node/8">
<div class="smallbox">
<div class="nounderline">
<strong>Website</strong><br>
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" width="233" height="157" alt="screenshot"><br>
Awareness Campaign<br>
HTML, CSS
</div>
</div></a></div>  </div>  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last">

  <div>        <div><a href="/node/7">
<div class="smallbox">
<div class="nounderline">
<strong>Website</strong><br>
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" width="233" height="157" alt=""><br>
Details Website<br>
HTML 5, CSS 3
</div>
</div></a></div>  </div>  </div>
    </div>






</div>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End other page specific content -->
</div><!--end middle-->
</div>
<div id="d">
<div id="footer">
;<a href="">Contact Form</a>
<br>
Copyright ©2012 My Name
</div>
</div>



<div id="lightbox2-overlay" style="display: none; "></div>      <div id="lightbox" style="display: none;" class="lightbox2-orig-layout">        <div id="outerImageContainer" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div id="modalContainer" style="display: none; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; "></div><div id="frameContainer" style="display: none; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; "></div><div id="imageContainer" style="display: none; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; "><img id="lightboxImage" alt=""><div id="hoverNav"><a id="prevLink" title="Previous" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; "></a><a id="nextLink" title="Next" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; "></a></div></div><div id="loading"><a href="#" id="loadingLink"></a></div></div>        <div id="imageDataContainer" class="clearfix" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); ">          <div id="imageData"><div id="imageDetails"><span id="caption"></span><span id="numberDisplay"></span></div><div id="bottomNav"><div id="frameHoverNav"><a id="framePrevLink" title="Previous" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; "></a><a id="frameNextLink" title="Next" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; "></a></div><a id="bottomNavClose" title="Close" href="#" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "></a><a id="bottomNavZoom" href="#"></a><a id="bottomNavZoomOut" href="#"></a><a id="lightshowPause" title="Pause Slideshow" href="#" style="display: none;"></a><a id="lightshowPlay" title="Play Slideshow" href="#" style="display: none;"></a></div></div>        </div>      </div></body></html>
```

And my CSS is as follows:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    background: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    }
a:visited{
    color: blue;
}
h2{
    font-size: 135%;
    margin: .2em 0;
}
#a{
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(140,79,84);
}
#bighead{
    height: 31em;
    width: 69em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
    background: url(../img/headerpic.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    border: 0 solid black;
    border-width: 0 4px;
}
#header a{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
#slogan{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: .5em;
}
#smallhead{
    height: 14em;
    width: 69em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../img/smallheader.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    border: 0 solid black;
    border-width: 0 4px;
}
#b{
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(50,51,46);
}
#menu{
    width: 69em;
    height: 2.5em;
    border: 0 solid black;
    border-width: 0 4px;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.item{
    font-size: 17.5px;
    height: 1.1em;
    width: 9.2em;
    float: left;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-top: .2em solid rgb(31,38,28);
    border-bottom: .2em solid rgb(31,38,28);
}
#menu a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCC;
}
#menu a:hover{
    color: white;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#c{
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(139,124,108);
}
#middle{
    min-height: 22.5em;
    width: 67.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0 solid black;
    border-width: 0 4px;
    background: rgb(98,103,109);
    padding: .75em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.title{
    font-size: 2em;
    height: .5em;
    width: 24em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    color: white;
}
.box{
    float: left;
    height: 17em;
    width: 17em;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: .5em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    background: rgb(49,49,51);
    color: white;
}
#contentwrapper{
}
#d{
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
#footer{
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 69em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.smallbox{
    float: left;
    height: 15em;
    width: 17em;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: .5em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    background: rgb(49,49,51);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.smallbox img{
    padding: .2em 0;
}
.nounderline{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your CSS and HTML?  Even better is if you could supply a http://jsfiddle.net/ for us with your code so we could check it out easily.  Also, note which browsers you're testing in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Since this was the first google result and didn't solve my issue: Check the anchor states, as it might need to be set in one of the others. (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply just to this view add:

```
.view-portfolio-page .views-row a { text-decoration: none; }
```

To apply to all views add:

```
 .views-row a { text-decoration: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D8kRE/

You were applying text-decoration: none to a div which has no effect. You can only apply that to an anchor tag which in your case is located at .views-row a.  You can get more specific and apply this to only the portfolio page view by using the code I've put above.

Comment: you *can* apply text-decoration to a DIV. User agents tend to define a text-decoration style on anchors that will override any value that's inherited, but there's nothing restricting text-decoration to links.

Comment: You're right in that a 'list-style-type' applied to a DIV will not have any immediate visible effect, unless the DIV is also set to display: list-item. But the difference is that text-decoration set on a DIV *will* have an immediate visible effect. And, in both cases, there are side-effects other than the immediately visible.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this came upon my search as well. So I thought I'd share.

I had a similar problem. I created a regular nav and setting the text-decoration to none worked fine.

Then I had to amend my css to create a hamburger menu effect for smaller viewports. And although I used the exact same css, the underline appeared and nothing I did would make it go away. I know it has something to do with the `toggle:checked & ~.mainNav` feature under which my nav needed to be placed, but I couldn't figure out why and how to get around it.

In any case, the one thing that DID work was going into my reset, and adding a default: `a {text-decoration: none}`

Don't know why it worked, but it did. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to the underline on the text, remember to set the text-decoration property to none on the ELEMENT. E.g.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none"> Google</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Edit:** Note, it is bad to use styling in-line with elements, I used it, just to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: I tried it using in-line styling on the link itself (I am aware that it is bad practice, but it should work just to test, correct?) and it did not help to problem.

Comment: Alright then. As mentioned before, I think some source code will be useful for others to try help you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `font-decoration: none`; try the css `text-decoration: none;`

Answer (score 0):

As this hasn't actually got a definitive answer yet and it's fairly high up on Google searches. I thought I would chip in with my answer.

I just had a similar problem where I couldn't pinpoint why I wasn't able to get rid of the underline and found out that it was because I didn't specify the hover state.

So try out

```
#header a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And that should work. I know this was posted ages ago, but I have seen that you haven't accepted an answer and didn't post whether you sorted it or not. So hopefully my input will help someone along the way and hopefully you can see this and finally accept an answer or make your own.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and found it was "box-shadow." See if you are lucky enough with these styles:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be a `text-decoration:` issue. It actually appears to be an issue with `border-bottom:`

Please check the instance of `border-bottom` in:

```
.item{
    font-size: 17.5px;
    height: 1.1em;
    width: 9.2em;
    float: left;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-top: .2em solid rgb(31,38,28);
    border-bottom: .2em solid rgb(31,38,28);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to add !important

`text-decoration: none !important;`

Comment: I tried it with no avail. Applied to the div outside of the box, the box itself, and a separate class inside of the box.

Comment: Indiscriminate slapping of "!important" against a declaration just because you don't understand why it's not working is *never* a good idea (http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/important-not-important)

Comment: @user1281809 are you enable css cache ? if so please clear the cache from `configuration >> performance`

Answer (score -1):

text-decoration works on anchor, it's correct name would be: anchor-decoration-for-text.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Dan Beaulieu: How does this not answer the question "Any ideas?"

Comment: Sure, this question showed up in stack overflows review queue for being of low quality. It was marked as such due to being so short and without formatting. I had a choice between selecting whether your answer was "ok" or "not ok". I chose not because it doesn't conform to stack overflows [answer] protocol. My comment above was automatically generated based on my choice. I can remove my comments, but your question will continue to show up in the review queue until you improve your answer.